# Method Reflect - When have class,method name and args;how to reflect a method

Tags: java, reflect

el:
defined some method such as:

```
  class AClass {
    public void dynamicMethod(String a, String... b) {
      log.info("dynamic String arg:" + a);
    }

    public void dynamicMethod(String a, Integer... b) {
      log.info("dynamic Integer arg:" + a);
    }

    public void dynamicMethod(String a, Object... b) {
      log.info("dynamic Object arg:" + a);
    }
  }
```

JVM can execute correctly:

```
    @Test
    public void testDynamicArgs() throws Exception {
        this.dynamicMethod("String", "s1", "s2");
        this.dynamicMethod("Integer", 1, 2);
        this.dynamicMethod("Object", "1", null, 2);
    }
```

console:

```
dynamic String arg:String
dynamic Integer arg:Integer
dynamic Object arg:Object
```

so when have class `this.getClass()`,method name `dynamicMethod`,args `"1", null, 2`;how to determine the right Method.Because arguments maybe contain `null` variable number or even both.Determine the parameter type in turn is not an efficient way.Is there a tool method provided in the JVM or other open source projects.

```
  public Method getMethod(Class<?> clazz, String methodName, Object[] args) {
    // TODO how write there;
  }
```

Comment: You want to find out which method Java would call, given a list of arguments?

Comment: yes, I want that